# Setup service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion error when installing SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, installation

How can I resolve the error I received when installing Microsoft SQL Server 2016?

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Setup service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

The following error has occurred:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1601.5&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%25400xDC80C325

---

BUTTONS:

&Retry

### Cancel

Comment: have you checked your `Windows Error Log` it will give a bit more details on why it cannot start the service.

Comment: Can you give some info on the environment - version of windows, spec of server/PC etc

Comment: Windows 2012 R2 x64

Comment: M. Ali, the Windows Error Log says sqlservr (2440) Error -1032 (0xfffffbf8) occurred while opening logfile C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\Api.log.

Comment: @Tarzan Which installer did you use to install SQL Server? I'm running into the same problem but none of the installers I've tried offer a "Retry" option.

Comment: I used a SQL Server 2016 installation disc purchased from Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the SQLRUserGroup to "Allow log on locally".

[image]

If you can't change Group Policy, temporarily add the `MSSQLServer01` to `MSSQLServer20` users to the local administrator group.

Click Re-try on the SQL Install and use the Log to confirm all `MSSQLServer<ID>` users are admins.

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ExtensibilityLog\EXTLAUNCHERRORLOG

The error in the log file is:

> LogonUser Failed for user MSSQLSERVER**01**. ErrorCode: 0x80070569.

When all MSSQLServer1-20 have access the installation will complete.

Comment: The installer does not have a "Re-try" option for me. The only way to retry is to uninstall the features that failed and then go through the whole installation again, but this also removes the SQLRUserGroup and MSSQLServer users in the process. How can I get around this? Are there different installers?

Comment: Must be different, my experience had a ReTry button like OP.

Comment: The policy sections were locked on my local machine, so I added the 20 users to the Administrators group. The install then worked fine. My users were called SQLEXPRESS00, SQLEXPRESS01, etc.