# The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion, when installing SQL Server 2017 Express on a VPS through RDC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2017 Express Edition on a Windows Server 2016 VPS through a remote desktop connection, using the web installer locally on the virtual machine. To my knowledge, all of the [hardware and software requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server) are satisfied.

I'm running the installation as the local Administrator account with full access. During installation I select "Default instance" rather than "Named instance" because I want to be able to connect using '.' or 'localhost', everything else is left default.
The installation completes with status "Failed" for the features Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search, Python, R, Machine Learning Services, Database Engine Services and SQL Server Replications, all of which log the following error:

> The following error has occurred:
>   The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

The Windows Application log contains the following error:

> Windows cannot access the file  for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit because of this error.

On the surface it seems like it may be the same issue as [this SO question about SQL Server 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579805/setup-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashio). The accepted answer there is to add the SQLRUserGroup to "Allow log on locally" in Local Security Policy and selecting the Re-try option. However, the SQL Server 2017 installer that I'm using does not offer this option. It can only be closed at this point. The only way to retry installation seems to be to uninstall the failed features, which also removes the MSSQLSERVER accounts and the SQLRUserGroup, and then go through the whole installation process again.

I have tried to completely uninstall and reinstall with no success. SQL Server 2016 has the same issue.

Below is the full log spit out by the installer

```
Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  WIN-6N8LFAODRDS
  Machine processor count:       2
  OS version:                    Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard (10.0.14393)
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2017 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2017
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       14
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         C:\SQLServer2017Media\ExpressAdv_ENU\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Express

Product Update Status:None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    true
  ENU:                           true
  EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad
  EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION, ADVANCEDANALYTICS, SQL_INST_MR, SQL_INST_MPY, FULLTEXT, CONN, BC, SDK, SNAC_SDK
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:     true
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      true
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391
  ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:         <empty>
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ISTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISWORKERSVCCERT:               <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBPORTRANGE:                   <empty>
  PBSCALEOUT:                    false
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  SQL
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
  SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         true
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           WIN-6N8LFAODRDS\Administrator
  SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY
  SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>
  SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            1
  SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
  SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  X86:                           false

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x80004005
  Error description:             The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325

  Feature:                       Python
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x80004005
  Error description:             The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325

  Feature:                       R
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x80004005
  Error description:             The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325

  Feature:                       Machine Learning Services (In-Database)
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x80004005
  Error description:             The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x80004005
  Error description:             The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x80004005
  Error description:             The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0xDC112D1C%400xDC80C325
```

Comment: Can you please add any info in the log files. You've obviously Install As Admin? You've used the default Local System, etc accounts during install? You've got the required hardware specs? You have disabled Antivirus software just during install?

Comment: @JeremyThompson I have updated my question with a bunch of additional details that might be relevant and a full copy of the log summary. If any of this gives you an idea of what might be wrong, I would be very grateful. Since posting the question, I have tried three different installers (express web, express offline and sql server evaluation version) and none of them have a "re-try" option. I double checked system requirements and verified I meet all of them. There's something in there about remote desktop that I'm not sure I fully understand but I _think_ it doesn't apply to me.

Comment: Its a permission error. Google for a Microsoft Exchange Server tool called `Err.exe`. Put it in your System32 folder so from any command line directory you can do a `Err 0x80004005` -> this will tell you the error as defined in the OS header file. This seems like a catch22, why do you have to **The only way to retry installation seems to be to uninstall the failed features** - make sure you have the 1- 20 accounts already set before install. I think I'm missing something critical to understanding this bit

Comment: @JeremyThompson I simply didn't realise that manually creating the users before installation was an option. I will give it a try and report back, though it seems tedious.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Creating the accounts before install does not work. Now the installation simply throws the error `An error occurred while creating local user account MSSQLSERVER00. The account already exists.`  and then proceeds to fail just as before.